# How to create dataframe from txt file of column_name: value where rows are delimited by empty line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a (2GB) txt file as follows

```
column_name_1: value_1_1

column_name_2: value_1_2

column_name_3: value_1_3


column_name_1: value_2_1

column_name_2: value_2_2

column_name_3: value_2_3
```

Meaning that the rows are delimited by a blank line and in each row the value of a column follows the name of said column after a " : ".

I would like to make it into a dataframe like

```
column_name_1      column_name_2      column_name_3
value_1_1          value_1_2          value_1_3
value_2_1          value_2_2          value_2_3
```

I have tried with pd.read_csv() and '\t', '\n', '\n' and '\n\n' as sep, but they either give error or make a dataframe with a single column of

```
column_name_1: value_1_1
column_name_2: value_1_2
column_name_3: value_1_3
column_name_1: value_2_1
```

.
.
.

I have also tried going first making a dictionary from the txt file and then going form dictionary to DataFrame, but the kernel crushes when I try to create the dictionary

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# read-in the csv with : as a delimiter
# it ends up with a two columns DF
df=pd.read_csv('csv2.txt', delimiter=":", header=None, names=['col1', 'col2'])


# groupby the col1, and aggregate columns2 as list
# convert it to a dict and then create a dataframe from the dict
df2=pd.DataFrame(dict(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(list)))
df2
```

```
    column_name_1   column_name_2   column_name_3
0   value_1_1   value_1_2   value_1_3
1   value_2_1   value_2_2   value_2_3
```